# Open a URL from windows service

Tags: windows, service

http://www.myserver.com/mypage.php?param1=abc&param2=123

I need to open this URL from a windows service either by IExplorer or without opening on windows startup.

OR

Can I submit an HTML form to my web server from a windows service on windows startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your requirements, the best way to do this might be by using [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx).  You can just write some code like this to accomplish the form post:

```
string url = "http://www.myserver.com/mypage.php?param1=abc&param2=123";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
// etc... read the response from the server here, if you need it
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Vista and later, services use a noninteractive window station and cannot interact with the user. Read [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/voy/archive/2007/02/23/services-isolation-in-session-0-of-windows-vista-and-longhorn-server.aspx) for more information.